# Combining two infinite algorithms to create a single infinite algortihm

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have an algorithm $F$ that, given a numeric input $x$, generates an infinite sequence of numbers that converges to a $f(x)$, where $f$ is some continuous real-valued function.

Similarly, I have an algorithm $G$ that, given a numeric input $y$, generates an infinite sequence of numbers that converges to $g(y)$, where $g$ is another continuous real-valued function.

I would like to have an algorithm $H$ that, given $x$, generates an infinite sequence of numbers that converges to $g(f(x))$. How can I do this?

My current idea is as follows. For every algorithm $A$ and integer $i$, let $A_i(x)$ be the $i$-th value in the sequence returned by algorithm $A$ when run on input $x$.

Then, the algorithm $H$ should return the sequence:

$$G_i(F_i(x))$$

Initially, $H$ runs a single step of $F$ on $x$ and runs a single step of $G$ on the result. Then, $H$ runs two steps of $F$ on $x$ and runs two steps of $G$ on the result. This goes on infinitely.

Is this idea correct? Is there a better idea?

Comment: Should one assume that $x$ and $y$ are numbers. What kind?  What are
the numbers generated (natural numbers, or reals, or computable reals,
or ...). How are they represented? What do you mean precisely by
converge. In the realm of algorithms and computability, this kind of
precision matters. --- --- Running infinite computations and giving them
meaning is also something to handle with care. It is often safer
mathematically to consider a function $F(x,i)$ which computes in
finiate time what you call $F_i(x)$. That can be handled by usual
Turing machines.

Comment: An infinite sequence of number can converge to a number. It is very unlikely to converge to a function, but it could be the value of a function on some input. BTW, but I am no specialist, I am afraid that the concept of convergence requires specific definitions in the context of computability.

Comment: You need more assumptions on the convergence for there to be any hope of an algorithm. As a counterexample for your specific suggestion, let $F_i(x) = 1/i$ and $G_i(x) = [xi < 1]$ ($[P]$ is the Iverson bracket). Clearly $g(f(x)) = 1$, but $G_i(F_i(x)) = 0$, and thus converges to the wrong thing.

Comment: @Hurkyl Your example does not work. $g(f(x)) = g(0) = 0$, not $1$ as you state.

Comment: @Kittsil: $G_i(0) = [0<1] = 1$ converges to $1$, so $ g(0) = 1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I added an assumption that the functions are continuous.

Comment: What theory of computation are you using, that handles infinite
enumerations, and the use of reals (rather than computable reals).
What is your goal? Because the computing technique you are suggesting
seems more theoretical than practical. Not to mention that infinity is
not a very practical concepts, one you can use to get a result.

Comment: @Erel: Is that enough? My guess was that you'd need something like uniform convergence here.

Comment: I can't nail down an example right now, but note that your setup does not seem to imply that the convergence rate is the same for all $x$. The outer function may amplify the error *faster* than the inner one converges, for $x \to \dots$.

Comment: I can't nail down an example right now, but note that your setup does not seem to imply that the convergence rate is the same for all $x$. The outer function may amplify the error *faster* than the inner one converges, for $x \to \dots$. In essence, that's @Hurkyl's objection: [pointwise convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) may not be enough for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

**Is this idea correct?**

(I apologize for my initial, poorly thought-out response to this question, and thank the commentors for pointing out the flaws.)

Your solution will work if $g(\cdot)$ is differentiable around $f(x)$.

Since $G(y)$ converges to $g(y)$, for any constant $\epsilon_G>0$ there exists some $N_G>0$ such that for *any* $y$ and all $i>N_G$, 
$$-\epsilon_G < G_i(y)-g(y) < \epsilon_G.$$

If $g(\cdot)$ is differentiable around $f(x)$, there exists constant $\epsilon_f>0$ such that $g(y)$ slopes toward $g(f(x))$ for all $y \in \left(f(x)-\epsilon_f, f(x)+\delta_g\right)$. Because $F$ converges to $f(x)$, there exists some $N_F>0$ such that for all $i>N_F$,
$$-\epsilon_f< F_i(x) - f(x) < \epsilon_f.$$

Since $g(\cdot)$ slopes toward $f(x)$ in the neighborhood containing all $F_i(x)$ for $i>N_F$, as $F(x)$ approaches $f(x)$, $g(F(x))$ approaches $g(f(x))$; i.e., $g(F_i(x))$ converges to $g(f(x))$. That is, for any $\epsilon_g>0$, there exists some $N_g>N_F$ such that for all $i>N_g$,
$$-\epsilon_g < g(F_i(x)) - g(f(x)) < \epsilon_g.$$

Now let $y=F_i(x)$. For any $\epsilon>0$, set $\epsilon_G = \epsilon_g = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then for all $i>N$ (where $N=\max(N_G, N_F, N_g)$),
$$-\epsilon = -(\epsilon_G+\epsilon_g) < G_i(F_i(x))-g(F_i(x)) + g(F_i(x)) - g(f(x)) < (\epsilon_G+\epsilon_g) = \epsilon,$$
or,
$$-\epsilon < G_i(F_i(x)) - g(f(x))) < \epsilon.$$
That is, $G_i(F_i(x))$ converges to $g(f(x))$.

---

**Is there a better idea?**

Probably. Your algorithm generates $O(i)$ numbers to create the $i$th output number.

Consider if the algorithms were finite (i.e., you stopped at the $n$th output). Then, you would run $F$ to $F_n(x)$, then run $G$ using this as your input. This would only take generating $O(n)$ numbers. Your problem is not finite, though.

However, you can choose some constant $c$ and only restart $G$ after every $c$ steps. That is, the $i$th output will be $G_i(F_{c\lfloor i/c\rfloor}(x))$. This will make the convergence less smooth, but it will help your running time; it will now only generate $O(i/c)$ (amortized) numbers to create the $i$th output number.

Comment: What do you mean by: "*Your algorithm takes O(i) to generate the ith output.*"? What is your computational model? What is a unit operation?

Comment: @babou Good point. I clarified that this counts the number of generated numbers.

Comment: Your second sentence used to be "Yes! It will definitely converge to
g(f(x))". You modified it to do away with @Hurkyl 's counter example.
How do you prove what you assert? That would avoid fear of new
counter-examples. --- --- Is your idea to only execute $F$ up to the
$n^{th}$ value, then call $G$ so as to reduce the number of
compuations of $G$?

Comment: You claim this will converge to $g(f(x))$ without any justification, but I think this needs a careful proof.  Do you have a proof of your answer?  If not, then it is a bit sketchy to simply assert that it works, without any caveats, when you don't know for sure whether this is true or not.

Comment: @D.W. I formalized the statement and added a proof.

Comment: Thank you for the proof attempt.  However, it looks to me like ther is a problem with the proof.  *"Since $G(y)$ converges to $g(y)$, for any constant $\epsilon_G>0$ there exists some $N_G>0$ such that for *any* $y$"* - This statement is incorrect.  The correct statement is: for all $y$ and all $\epsilon_G>0$, there exists $N_G>0$ such that (...).  You have got the order of quantifiers wrong.  In general, $\epsilon_G$ can depend on $y$.  The convergence of the sequence $G(y)$ does not imply there is a single $\epsilon_G$ that works for all $y$.

Comment: Also, the paragraph beginning *"Since $g(\cdot)$ slopes toward $f(x)$..."* seems imprecise and unclear.  The notion of "slopes toward" is not defined formally, and it's not clear what you mean by "as $F(x)$ approaches $f(x)$": $x$ is a fixed number, so $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ are fixed numbers too, not sequences -- it doesn't make any sense to say something like "as 5.5 approaches 5.7"...  A mathematical proof should be more precise.

Comment: @D.W. $N_G$ is the supremum of the $N$ required for any $y \in$ **R**; therefore, because $G$ converges for any $y$, it does exist for *any* $y$. Furthermore, $F(x)$, as defined by the question, is an infinite series which does appraoch $f(x)$.

Comment: *"supremum of all $N$"* - what's $N$?  You haven't defined $N$.  Anyway, the supremum of an infinite set of real numbers is not guaranteed to exist (or, to put it another way, it might be $\infty$), in which case your argument breaks.  Take a look at what happens in your argument if you try to set $N_G=\infty$; you'll see that your proof totally falls apart.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum for more about supremums.  Bottom line: This "proof" ain't valid.

Comment: Also, it's still not clear to me what "As $F(x)$ approaches $f(x)$" means.  If what you really mean is "$F(x)$ converges to $f(x)$", you should say that.  Use standard terminology -- it exists for a reason.  And even then, if we make that modification, it's not clear what that sentence was supposed to mean.  Did you mean "Since $F(x)$ converges to $f(x)$, it follows that $g(F(x))$ converges to $g(f(x))$"?  If so, this statement needs justification/proof.  Just saying that it follows "since $g(\cdot)$ slopes towards $f(x)$..." is not a justification.